# How to get refresh token on my page using USER AGENT flow of salesforce?

Tags: rest-api, salesforce1-app, user, refresh-token

I am a beginner in **Angular JS** and **Salesforce**.

I am building a **hybrid** application.

I am using the [USER AGENT authentication flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_user_agent_oauth_flow.htm)

I used the following **url :**

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=consumer_key&***redirect_uri=https://localhost:63342/www/index.html#/***

I got the result as expected with the access token but did not get the refresh token.

Then i found this

**The refresh token is only returned if the redirect URI is https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success or used with a custom protocol that is not HTTPS.**

So I changed the **redirect_uri** in my **url as :**

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=3MVG9ZL0ppGP5UrCf3JELrQofxTN1p28Y0qBjNy67uUtwoVl8i0LX6ntfchfUlDJoeso1xKRxGHx_Tzk_SAiK&***redirect_uri=https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success***

I got the refresh token.

But then the page is stuck up at the below link

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success#access_token=access_token&refresh_token=refresh_token&instance_url=https%3A%2F%2Fap2.salesforce.com&id=id&issued_at=1444119251446&signature=sign&scope=scope&token_type=Bearer

How do i make it redirect back to my app link

https://localhost:63342/www/index.html#/

***Thanks*** in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the Answer.

I just changed the callback url in connected app settings to my app url and we have to use http instead of https.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution.  Please accept your answer as the solution to close your question.

Comment: can you post the example url here?

Answer (score 0):

This only works because your redirect uri is a localhost. The redirect uri needs to satisfy these conditions:

[image]

http://localhost is also another condition that will allow the refresh_token to be passed back.

**Reference Resource:** https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5